# Как добавить возможность прикреплять место на карте на сайт?

Tags: html, google-maps

Хочу создать форму, которую человек будет заполнять, и одним из пунктов заполнения "указать место на карте", например GoogleMaps. Реально ли вообще такое реализовать?

А потом все эти места на карте, к примеру выводить на главной странице.

Если такое возможно, дайте пожалуйста ссылку, где можно про это почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Сохранять координаты места в базу данных, затем в нужном месте выводить карту с маркерами. Вот пример создания маркера https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=ru